# My PS3 controller won’t connect when it is in safe mode

Tags: ps3, controllers

Accidentally put my PS3 into safe mode, when I turn it on now a message comes up saying connect the controller using a USB cable, and then press the PS button.

Comment: Well, did you try connecting your controller via cable and pressing the PS button?

Comment: Yes I did I don’t know what to do next

Comment: Please please can you help me try and fix my ps3